# How to create SIP server for my android?

Tags: android, sip

I am developing an Android application, in which I want to make a calls using internet using `SIP` in android. So I need to maintain my own SIP sever for my app users, how can I create my own SIP server?

Answer (score 6):

I would not advise creating your our [sip](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) server as it would take a large number of man years of development and there are a lot of pitfalls.

There are some open source implementations that you could install and setup yourself.  Like [FreeSwitch](https://www.freeswitch.org/) or [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/).  Both are large and complete to setup as there is a lot of domain knowledge required to understand how to set them up correctly.

There are also free server that you could try out as well like [Sip2Sip](https://mdns.sipthor.net/register_sip_account.phtml).

Then there is the job of creating a sip client on Android.  Again it's not that simple either.  I would look at using a open source library here as well, like [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/).  This gives you the advantage of being able to look at examples of full sip clients already developed for Android like [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/).  pjsip also has the advantage of being cross-platform, so you could reuse it in IOS for example.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

### The Server

As a communication server, choose for example  sip:providerCE v2.6. The easiest way to get started with it is to download the VMware or Virtualbox image and fire it up on a suitable machine. If you get more serious, you want to install the system from scratch on a dedicated server with a public static IP. If you’re new to VoIP and SIP, do NOT try to install it on an Amazon EC2 instance, as they’re using destination NAT, which is a big pain for SIP and needs some experience with the SPCE to tweak it properly for that scenario.

Note that the SPCE is a 64bit system, so in order to run the VM images, you need to turn on 64bit CPU virtualization in your BIOS if VMware or Virtualbox warns you about it.

...There is very good tutorial [HERE](http://www.sipwise.com/news/technical/byov-skype-replacement/)! on how to set things up.

...Don't forget there is a technical advise concerning SIP [check the accepted ANS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607235/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-sip-application-with-audio-codecs-only?rq=1")!

...Least but not last check [THIS](http://www.voip-info.org)! VOIP Wiki, It covers everything related to VOIP.

Answer (score 1):

I used uSIPserver on android. It works well and support video call. If you use client app which supports video then you can video call eachother on wifi.
It is so simple to use.

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

SIP RFC is very easy protocol to implement. Just create a socket listener and implement RFC-3261. Start with with a basic codec GSM, then move up to A-LAW (G.711), as needed.

The tricky parts with SIP are (A) ensuring your call flows are correct (RFC-3665) and (B) media encoding/compresion.  Use Asterisk (FreeSwitch) and WireShark to test your call flow.  If you need DTMF support you'll need RFC-2833. If you need advanced codecs, consider using open-source library like FFMPEG.